# What are some Angularjs based client-side frameworks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, frameworks, sails.js

I want to build rich Angularjs based applications, but I don't want to invent my own framework if I don't have to. I need something that can organize and watch my Angularjs code, which I'm writting in coffeescript, auto-compile and link separate modules by convention over configuration. This isn't going to be framework that is concerned with building anything that has to do with server side code. This is purely a frontend framework. I'm not looking for server side frameworks like sails.

Answer (score 2):

While angularjs is a "toolset for building the framework most suited to you". It sounds more like you're looking for a development stack.

There are a lot of pre-compilers, task runners, development guidelines (not in any particular order of favoritism)

- [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack)
- es6 and the [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) compiler
- [yo-grunt-bower](http://yeoman.io/)
- requirejs and r.js
- anything you want and the tools provided with:

  - [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)-[contrib](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib)
  - [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp) or
  - [broccoli](https://www.npmjs.org/package/broccoli)

While most of these are collections of tools to help you do what you want. Things like yeoman give you a nice baseline you can add to, ie -> throw a coffee-script compiler in your grunt workflow.